# Android: How can I run a JUnit4 test in my data layer without using an Activity or Service?

Tags: android, android-testing

I am testing my data layer (`androidTest`), which is an `android-library` gradle module - which means no activity or service to hook into.

I can use `ApplicationTest` - but it is JUnit3. How come there is no `ApplicationTestRule` like `ActivityTestRule` or `ServiceTestRule`, so we can use JUnit4?

Comment: Um, if you are looking for a `Context` for the code under test, use `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()`. Otherwise, please explain what you are looking to get out of an `ApplicationTestRule`.

Comment: ^^you are right! my bad